# Is there such a thing as a posix lstatat call?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, posix

I am working on a FUSE and I have a file descriptor to the directory prior to mounting the fuse on top. I want to use that handle to read/write files with state information underneath the FUSE mounted file system, and then to be able to access that data next time I mount it.  So I cannot use the normal lstat call since it won't see the files I want to access, but the files FUSE exposes instead.  What I need is the equivalent of fstatat that works for symbolic links, since fstatat apparently gives the the stat info on the file the symbolic link points to, not the symbolic link itself.  Yet I cannot find documentation for such a function.  Does it exist?  Am I thinking of an incorrect name?

Comment: `man fstatat`: *AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW
              If  pathname is a symbolic link, do not dereference it: instead return information about
              the link itself, like lstat().  (By default, fstatat() dereferences symbolic links, like
              stat().)*

Comment: No, POSIX does not define `lstatat()` yet.  Check the POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm, follow System Interfaces (in the LHS box), and then System Interfaces again (different location) — it will give you a list of all the functions specified, and `lstatat()` is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `lstatat()` function in POSIX.  However, [`fstatat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html) takes a flag argument which can be `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW`,
which is what you're looking for.